# Detect if the user edits the Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect if the user alters the javascript send to the client?

What i want is:

This should not fire the function:

```
User opens the debug window by a mistake ->
Nothing happens.
```

This should fire the function:

```
User opens the debug window ->
The user makes changes to the Javascript ->
Fire "You cheated" function.
```

Is this possible? If it is, how reliable is it?

**Why do i need this?**

I'm making a clicking game with leaderboards. Since it's a clicking game, i can't just send everything to the server as soon as the user clicks the elements.

An average person can "burst click" the mouse about 15-20 times/second for about 1 minutes straight. This would instantly overload the server.

I have been doing something like this in the past:

```
Every 10 seconds run this pseudo function:

$.ajax({
    url: 'updateScore',
    data: {'score' : game.Score, 'time' : 'currentTime'},
})
```

*At the updateScore i do this:*

```
Get the current score and last-edited-time from DB 

$differenceScore = game.Score - DB.score;
$differenceTime = $diff = strtotime(game.Time) - strtotime(DB.last-edited-time)
$averageClickingSpeed = 17.5
if( ( $differenceScore / $averageClickingSpeed) < $differenceTime){
    // Do DB stuff
} else {
    // The user cheated, or had an avg clicking speed of more than 17.5
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is possible, what if they edit the part of the Javascript that checks whether they edited the Javascript?

Comment: @Barmar well... shit... didn't think of that.

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly ? If it's a security issue just validate everything on the server.

Comment: Making a game with leaderboards. If you cheat, you'll get flagged in the database, and you will not be shown on the leaderboards

Comment: Why would that matter, the original page would remain same on server side.Besides people often modify webpage JS sources using firebug etc for testing purposes. If your server app is robust enough it should not any make difference.

Comment: Yeah, but Bob could potentially put this into his firebug:

`Game.currentPoints = 9999999999` and then hit save.

Comment: As Mustafa sabir just said you should make sure to validate the users actions on the server.

Comment: stop points calculation on the client side

Comment: Move all the game logic server side and view logic client side. Use ajax to glue them together

Comment: Caweren, it would be your server's job to figure out if 9999999999 points could have really been earned by the player.